# How are colours assigned to the World vs. World vs. World servers?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm pretty sure that lots of players are trying, as I am, to complete the whole map exploration, and even if I didn't believe when I read that the hardest part could be WvWvW, I must change my mind, it is really hard, due to the team colour allocation of servers...

Being more specific, I'm on Whiteside Ridge and it's like since 2/3 months that I go to WvWvW at least once a week, to be sure to catch up every new match, and so every new colour... but we never been (as far as I started to do it) in the green team, making it quite impossible to break through enemy lands to complete my last map exploration.

So now, to the question, how is the colour assigned to the three matched servers? Is it statically given based on the leaderboard position? Like 1st, 4th, 7th and so on always green, 2nd, 5th, 8th and so on always blue and the other ones always red? Or is there a chance that even if the leaderboard will not change, my server could finally switch to green?

Comment: Don't bank on spawning in the right world zone to complete it's map. You'll have to go run around in enemy territory to complete the map.

Comment: But isn't there like a vista in the main map city which is filled with immortal legendary defenders and where every player of that server is also immortal and so you cannot hope to get it? (Also getting the enemy garrison can be a pain for a weak server...)

Comment: No, no there isn't.

Comment: This gives me relief... I'll try fueling a rebellion against the current green server then... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server's WvW colour (i.e. green/blue/red) is determined by your current matchup and rank. As you suspect, the top team in each set of three currently gets assigned to green, the second to blue, and the third to red (currently this happens weekly). The reasoning behind this is that red is (only ever so slightly, since the three Borderlands maps are identical and the Eternal Battlegrounds are very similar for all three sides) easier than blue while green is (ever so slightly) harder.

To see your current position and likely next position, you can have a look at http://mos.millenium.org/matchups#NA which is updated regularly with scores and has more information than [ANet's own leaderboards](https://leaderboards.guildwars2.com/en/na/).

The good news is that plans were [recently announced on the forums](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/pvp/wuvwuv/Can-we-PLEASE-rotate-the-colours-more/first#post1774463) to rotate the colours more often, which will allow you to more easily explore WvW from a different starting point (of course, being WvW, there are no guarantees that anyone will be in control of specific areas at any given time). As Devon Carver states in a later post in the same thread, "While [world completion] would certainly be a side effect of the change, I’d like to do it because it will add a small amount of variety to the matchups, nothing more and nothing less."

To address your concern in your comment to your question, there is nothing you need to "discover" for world completion that depends on which Borderland is yours. The only thing in areas reachable for only one team are waypoints, but since they're all marked as discovered by default, nothing is unreachable. Of course some POIs and vistas require access to certain garrisons etc., so you'll have to hope your side captures them unless you're willing to switch servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice link to a very nice site... can you please explain me why the red map should be slightly easier than the other two? Anyway, I'm not willing to switch server, and I know how hard it can be to capture enemy garrison, expecially because if we are red, it means we're the weaker server in the matchup, so we're likely to lose... :P

Comment: It mostly has to do with the positioning of the keeps and towers. Green's area is (arguably) the hardest to defend, while red's keep is in a commanding higher position, able to use trebuchets to bombard Stonemist Castle without easy treb retaliation. Blue's keep has tricky terrain around it (which can be good and bad) but its towers go down easier... Of course, most of this is subjective and other people may have different opinions. But the point is not actually what _we_ think, it's what _ANet_ thought when they designed it. ;-)

Comment: After commenting your answer I started looking around about those map differences in the forum and actually found out people claiming that green is easier to defend... other thought that blue was better... and so on... so I think you're right... it's mostly subjective... :)